# Initializing arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I need to create an empty 30 by 30 array and fill it with dots using a double for loop. I am stuck in how to write the array and fill it with dots. I am very new to programming, this is far from correct, but what I have managed to write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cols = 30;
int rows = 30;
int i;
int j;

int main()
{

char intial_map[30][30];

    for(char i=0; i<=cols; ++i)
    {
        for(char j=0;j<=rows; ++j)
        {
            intial_map[i][j] = .
            scanf(“%d”, &intial_map[i][j]); 
        }
    }
    return 0;}
```

Comment: `char` literals must be in single quotes (and you forgot a semi-colon), so you want `= '.';`, not `= .`. That said, you're replacing the value via `scanf` on the next line, so I have no idea why you need to put a `.` there. Also, you used the `%d` format code, when you almost certainly want the `%c` code (`%c` to read one character).

Comment: Why do you include a call to `scanf()` in your loop and what does that has to do with filling the array with dots?

Comment: Don't use `i` and `j` as global variables.  In fact, you probably don't want `cols` and `rows` as global variables either, but single-letter global variables are almost invariably a bad idea (I can't immediately think of extenuating circumstances).

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

You need to make sure to quote your literals. In this case, the compiler is viewing your `.` as the member-of-structure operator. You need to enclose it in single quotes (double quotes are for string literals) to inform the compiler that it is a literal and not an operator. Also, you need to terminate your statement with a semicolon.

Apart from that, you have an off-by-one error in your `for` loop. You need to use the `<` operator as the termination condition rather than the `<=` operator. By using the '<=' operator, the `for` loop is still run for `i = 30`, however, this is outside of the array bounds and may cause an error, as C arrays are 0-indexed. In addition, there is also little advantage to using a `char` counter instead of an `int` counter in the `for` loop. This could also lead to unexpected integer overflow.

You are redefining `i` and `j`, which are defined globally, in your `for` loop initializers. This is allowed in C, but should be avoided if possible as it is confusing. You should either remove the global `i` and `j`, or change the `for` loops so they do not declare new counters.

Your `scanf()` call in the loop body makes no sense, unless you are trying to prompt the user for the map data.

You can define `rows` and `cols` as preprocessor macros so that they can easily be adjusted at compile-time.

A bit more opinion based: try to keep your indentation consistent throughout your code, it makes it much easier to read.

Putting all of these together gives you this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define cols 30

#define rows 30

int main()
{
    char initial_map[rows][cols];

    for(int i=0; i<cols; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<rows; ++j)
        {
            initial_map[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As a side note, it is possible to achieve the same effect with a single line of code:

```
char initial_map[30][30];
memset(initial_map, '.', sizeof(initial_map));
```

Comment: This was very helpful thank you! However, when i compile my program, nothing prints. Do I need to include a printf() statement? Again I am very new at this, this is one of my first programs I have written in C

Comment: Yes, this simply initializes your array. To print it, you must loop over each line and print each element.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `intial_map[i][j] = .` to `intial_map[i][j] = '.'`. A dot without quote is undefined here, not a char.

Comment: You'd need to add the missing semicolon too.  And that just scratches the surface of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to fill your 2D array with dots, then you don't have to use `scanf` function, just use the assignment operator `=`:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int cols = 30;
    int rows = 30;

    int i;
    int j;

    char intial_map[30][30];

    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            intial_map[i][j] = '.';
            putchar(initial_map[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Beware that the above code will not NUL-terminate the arrays.

Comment: This was very helpful thank you! However, when I compile my program, nothing prints. Do I need to include a printf() statement? Again I am very new at this, this is one of my first programs I have written in C

Comment: You have to pass a NUL-terminated string to printf,otherwise you'll invoke undefined behavior.To print the above arrays,use 2 loops similar to the above and call putchar function.

Comment: @EvaHeller I edited the code so that it prints the dots to the screen.

Comment: You probably want a `putchar('\n');` after the inner loop.